# ITRS Geneos monitoring

Tags: monitoring, geneos

We are using Geneos to monitor our servers and processes.

We have a requirement to display 'agedays' column i.e. the time since process has been running in Geneos display view. As per geneos help, agedays is predefined attribute.

Does anyone has any idea on how to configure this?

Comment: Which OS? Are you using Processes plug-in to monitor processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your netprobe is running on a Windows server you can use the toolkit plug-in to call a powershell script which returns the required data in csv format. A simple powershell script to get processes information would be:

```
$Now = GET-DATE
Get-Process | 
Select-Object id, name, starttime , @{n="AgeDays";e={NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $_.starttime –End $Now}} | 
Sort-Object id |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Advanced Tab of the "processes" plugin there is a "Process parameters" section.

- ageh - age of the process in hours
- aged - age of the process in days
- agem - age of the process in minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you want how long the job is running then you need to create an action and a rule .

define the target in that rule and link that action to that rule .later you can set the value in the block code.

such as you want alert when job running more than 10 Mins :

```
**if value > 360 then 
   severity critical    run "MY-Job-LONG-RUNNING" 
else    severity ok endif**
```

---